# Blue screen and blinking instead of desktop

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I get a blue screen after logging in on Ubuntu 16.04 (started after froze completely the other day).

dmesg | tail showed an error 6 in libnvidia-glcore.so

I did `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` to rid the Nvidia module (sometimes reinstalling a couple times helps on some ancient Nvidia cards), even without that it complatins about `error 4 in libnux-graphics-4.0.so.0.8.0`

In fact, after reinstall I see segfault in libnux-graphics, and nvidia-glcore.so.384. Should I be checking something else to see why it's a white grainy screen or blue screen at boot up?

Guest session does a similar thing with white, then blue screen and only a cursor.